# How to build a DSL for looking up fields from a record in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dsl

**TL;DR:** I need help figuring out how to generate code that will return one of a small number of data types (probably just Double and Bool) from various fields on disparate records.

**Long form:** Assuming the following data types

```
data Circle = Circle { radius :: Integer, origin :: Point }
data Square = Square { side  :: Integer }
```

and some boilerplate code

```
circle = Circle 3 (Point 0 0)
square = Square 5
```

I'm building a small DSL, and want the user to be write something like the following

```
circle.origin
square.side
```

and it will generate code similar to

```
origin . circle
side . square
```

In parsing this, I would have the strings "circle" and "origin" for example. I now need to turn those into function calls. I could obviously have something like this:

```
data Expr a = IntegerE (a -> Integer)
            | PointE (a -> Point)

lookupF2I "side"   = Just $ IntegerE side
lookupF2I "radius" = Just $ IntegerE radius
lookupF2I _        = Nothing

lookupF2P "origin" = Just $ PointE origin
lookupF2P _ = Nothing
```

and have one lookup function per returned data type. Having one function per data type is practical from the DSL point of view in that it will only really deal with 2 or 3 data types. However, this hardly seems like a particularly effective way of doing things. Is there a better way (surely) of doing this? If not, is there a way that I can generate the code for the various lookup functions from the various records that I want to be able to lookup fields from?

Secondly, there's still the matter of the parsed `"circle"` or `"square"` needing to call the appropriate `circle` or `square` function. If I were to implement this using type classes, I could do something like:

```
instance Lookup Circle where
    lookupF2I "radius" = Just $ IntegerE radius
    lookupF2I _        = Nothing
    lookupF2P "origin" = Just $ PointE origin
    lookupF2P _        = Nothing
```

but then that leaves me with having to figure out which type to enforce on the lookup function, *and* worse having to hand write instances for each (of many) records that I want to use this on.

Note: The fact that `Circle` and `Square` could be represented using a single ADT is incidental to my question in that this is a contrived example. The actual code will entail various very different records, of which the only thing they have in common is having fields of the same type.

Comment: I would look at the Lens package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.1 and also at Vinyl https://github.com/jonsterling/Vinyl

Comment: +1 for `lens`.  It has Template Haskell support so that you can automatically build lenses from data types.  Then your parsing code just translates the strings to their corresponding lenses.

Comment: It looks like you are embedding your DSL with some sort of HOAS (higher order abstract syntax) that uses functions from the meta-language (Haskell) in the embedded language. If you want some notes on using HOAS then look at the "Unembedding" paper by Robert Atkey and co-writers https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/robert.atkey/unembedding.html. If HOAS means nothing to you, then you are probably best off with normal first order abstract syntax - represent builtin functions with an identifier and evaluate with an environment containing a lookup to the primitive functions.

Comment: PS it's not very clear from your question what sort of DSL you intend. Are you wanting groovy syntax for Haskell records - if so looking at Lenses is appropriate and my comment is irrelevant? Or are you wanting to embed a language of with Expressions and generate code for it, if so my comment has more relevance?

Comment: @user5402 Thanks, I knew about Lens, but hadn't heard of Vinyl. It looks pretty cool :)

Comment: @stephentetley yeah, in a sentence you were able to describe exactly what I'm trying to do :) The best I've come up with so far is having a function `lookupF f = return . VarE $ mkName f` and then calling it `$(lookupF "parsedFunctionNameAsString")`, but that feels rather hacky. The paper you linked to looks great; I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using Template Haskell to provide a nice and type safe way to solve this problem. To do this, I constructed the expressions from a given string.

I suppose that Lens package can do that, but it may be a simpler and more flexible solution.

It can be used like this:

```hs
import THRecSyntax
circleOrigin = compDSL "circle.origin.x"
```

And is defined like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH

compDSL :: String -> Q Exp
compDSL s = return 
            $ foldr1 AppE 
            $ map (VarE . mkName) 
            (reverse $ splitEvery '.' s)
```

So the result expression will be: `x (origin circle)`

Note: `splitEvery` is a function that splits a list into sublists taking out the given element. Example implementation:

```hs
splitEvery :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitEvery elem s = splitter (s,[])
  where splitter (rest, res) = case elemIndex elem rest of
            Just dotInd -> let (fst,rest') = splitAt dotInd rest
                            in splitter (tail rest', fst : res)
            Nothing -> reverse (rest : res)
```

This is a heavyweight but type-safe way to create an embedded DSL with the given syntax.

Comment: I don't know how I missed seeing your answer until now. Thank you for taking the time to write one up :)